# Chef : Bootstrapping a node multiple times

Tags: chef-infra

I am testing multiple cookbooks and with each cookbook I am bootstrapping my node repeatedly (only for testing purpose).
When I run chef-client on my node, I get below error:

```
***************************************

[2017-04-17T20:13:20-07:00] WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/client.pem>

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "XXXX.com"
================================================================================

Private Key Not Found:
----------------------
Your private key could not be loaded. If the key file exists, ensure that it is 
readable by chef-client.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
validation_key "/etc/chef/validation.pem"

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

****************************************
```

I am using validatorless bootstrap (--bootstrap-vault-json).
Can someone let me know why I am getting this error.
I remember that i was able to run "chef-client" during initial bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Without pointing out the obvious too much, this means either you removed the private key file `/etc/chef/client.pem` or you're not running Chef as root so it can't read that file. Make sure you are using `sudo chef-client` if you aren't already root.